# Check if a (possibly nested) list is real

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, code-review

I have a very large matrix of numbers. I want to check if all its entries are real. At the moment I am using

```
realQ = And @@ Thread[Flatten[Im @ #] == 0] &
```

Is there any faster/safer/better way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to check if an expression is a real-valued number](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18647) With the `realQ` from this link, you just need to do `MatrixQ[mat, realQ]`

Comment: To check each element, first take a look at rm's link, then use things like `VectorQ[..., realQ]`, `MatrixQ[..., realQ]`,  `ArrayQ[..., _, realQ]`, etc.

Comment: .......`TensorQ`