# Assuming reals of unknown variables in a Matrix valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, assumptions

I am trying to write a generic matrix valued function in a package, of the form:

```
f[matrix_] := Module[...]
```

My problem is that I want to accept any matrix, but always assume that the functions/variables contained within the matrix are real. I realise that I can set assumptions when doing calculations, but for this it seems that I need to know the functions or variables before hand in order to set the assumptions up. How can I tell mathematica that any element of the matrix should be assumed to be real?

For clarification, lets say I do `f[{{x,x^2},{h[x],S[y]^2}}]`. I want mathematica to *assume* that `x, x^2, h[x] and S[y]` are all functions only involving real numbers, so I don't get `Conjugate(S[y]^2)` type answers in the output of my function.

Comment: Maybe `real[m : {{__Real} ..}] := m * 10`

Comment: This is why you should put more effort in asking clear questions from the get go.

Comment: I thought it was quite clear, but obviously not! What was unclear @RunnyKine?

Comment: I just meant your clarification would have been nice from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update:* after clarification I propose

```
f[m_] := Block[{$Assumptions = Alternatives @@ Flatten@m ∈ Reals}, 
  Conjugate[m[[1, 1]]] // Simplify]

f[{{x, x^2}, {h[x], S[y]^2}}]
(* x *)
```

---

Previous test-based answer:

From the documentation of `MatrixQ`

> Test if a matrix has real numeric entries:
>
> ```
> MatrixQ[{{Pi, Sin[1]}, {Cos[2], E}}, Im[#] == 0 &]
> ```
>
> Faster test for real-valued numbers:
>
> ```
> MatrixQ[{{1, 2.}, {3/4, 5`20}}, NumberQ[#] && ! MatchQ[#, _Complex] &]
> ```

So you can use

```
real[m_ /; MatrixQ[m, Im[#] == 0 &]] := m
```

or

```
real[m_ /; MatrixQ[m, NumberQ[#] && ! MatchQ[#, _Complex] &]] := m
```

For big matrices the following will be considerably faster

```
ClearAll[real]
real[m_ /; MatrixQ[m] && Norm[Im[m], ∞] == 0] := m

real[RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}]] // Head // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.332791, List} *)
```

*Note:* My method accept complex arrays with zero imaginary part.

- If you don't want to accept, use kguler's solution.
- If you want to accept and get rid of the imaginary part just use `Re[m]` inside the function.

Comment: I'm not dealing with numeric matrices, and I don't want to 'test' to see if it's real. I want Mathematica to assume that any functions inside the matrix are real, so I avoid Conjugate(function) etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
rmQ = MatrixQ[#, Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] &;

ClearAll[realB, real]
real[m_ /; MatrixQ[m] && Norm[Im[m], \[Infinity]] == 0] := m
realB[m_?rmQ] := m

real[RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}]] // Head // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.312443,List} *)
realB[RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}]] // Head // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.093755,List} *)
```

See also: [How to check if an expression is a real-valued number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18647/125)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
 validNum = Except[_Complex, _?NumericQ];
 f[m : {{validNum ..} ..}] := m
```

`f` will accept a wide variety number forms but not complex numbers.

```
f[{{1, 2.}, {3/4, π}, {5, 6}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2.}, {3/4, π}, {5, 6}}
> ```

```
f[{{1 + I, 2.}, {3/4, π}, {5, 6}}]
```

> ```
> f[{{1 + I, 2.}, {3/4, π}, {5, 6}}]
> ```

Nor will it accept forms that are not matrix-like.

```
{f[], f[1], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{{1, 2.}, π, {5, 6}}]}
```

> ```
> {f[], f[1], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{{1, 2.}, π, {5, 6}}]}
> ```

However, it does not care if the matrix rows are not all the same length.

```
 f[{{1, 2.}, {π}, {5, 6}}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2.}, {π}, {5, 6}}
> ```