# Testing for a vector of reals

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, number-representation

Suppose I define:

```
RealVector[expr_]:=VectorQ[expr,NumberQ[#]&&Head[#]===Real)];
```

Then:

```
RealVector[{1,2,3}];  RealVector[{1.,2.,3.}];
```

should evaluate to `False` and `True`, resp.  But I get `False` and `False`. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: related: [Real Numbers in the Wolfram Language](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69525/5478)

Comment: The reason is you need a `&`: `RealVector[expr_] := VectorQ[expr, NumberQ[#] && Head[#] === Real &]`

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica, `Element[1,Reals]` returns `True` since integers are subset of the reals. But `Head[1]` is Integer. So, since you need to check for `Head` of each element. One way might be

```
realVector[x_List] := VectorQ[x, NumericQ] && (AllTrue[x, (Head[#] === Real) &])
```

Now

```
 realVector[{1., 2., 3.}]  (*True*)
 realVector[{1, 2, 3}]  (*False*)
 realVector[{1., 2., 3}] (*False, since one element is not Real*)
 realVector[{Pi, 1., 2.}] (*False*)
```

btw, you do not need `VectorQ[x, NumericQ]` in the above, but I thought it might be faster to short circuit the test. You can also just use

```
 realVector[x_List] := AllTrue[x, (Head[#] === Real) &]
```

And this should work also.

Comment: Thanks!  The & at the end does the trick.  BTW, I dont have AllTrue in the Mathematica version I am using, but it is not needed.  The function is used in 8 print modules in a finite element program.  If the vector is all reals, entries are printed using PaddedForm[<entry>,{d,f}] to equalize decimals.  If not, InputForm[<entry>] is used to accommodate symbolic entries.

Answer (score 2):

Does this fit your needs?

```
RealVector = MatchQ[#, {__Real}] &
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors (e.g., no & for making a function).  Moreover, there is no need to check if an element is a number if you're also checking whether it is in the set of Reals.

This should work for you:

```
realVector[expr_] := VectorQ[expr, # \[Element] Reals &];
```

Comment: David, your solution returns `True` for `realVector[{1, 2, 3}]`, I think the OP wants this to return `False`. This happens because integer also returns `True` for `Element[#,Reals]`, so a `Head` test is needed.

Comment: An integer is a real number.