# Testing for a vector of all reals

Tags: expression-test

I want to test if an expression is a vector of all reals. I defined

```
RealVector[expr_]:=VectorQ[expr,NumberQ[#]&&(Head[#]===Real)];
```

Trying this on

```
RealVector[{1,2,3}]; RealVector[{1.,2.,3.}];
```

should return `False` and `True`, resp., but I get `False` and `False`. I do not
understand what is wrong.  Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: You missed the `&` after the pure function.  Use `NumberQ[#]&&(Head[#]===Real) &`.  Note the `&` at the end.  The `#` signs should show as green in the notebook when used correctly, not pink.

Comment: That said, this is simpler: `realVectorQ[{___Real}] = True; realVectorQ[__] = False`

Comment: I just noticed that [you have already posted the same question yesterday](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72580/testing-for-a-vector-of-reals), and received the same response.  Why did you post again?  If you need additional clarifications, please explain what exactly was not clear in the answers people already gave you. Then people can explain. Re-postig the exact same question won't yield better results.

Comment: Integers are reals.

Comment: If you want to distinguish Integers from the other Reals:  `realVector[expr_] := VectorQ[expr, # \[Element] Reals && # \[NotElement] Integers &]`