# Selecting positive real numbers from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Is there a short method to select positive real numbers from a list containing both reals and complex numbers? Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

My guess:

```
Select[list, Positive]
```

This is also quite efficient with larger lists...

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {1, 11.2, -12, a, 10 + I};

Cases[list, s_ /; Im[s] == 0 && s > 0]
```

{1, 11.2}

Comment: Thank you very much! I now my question is simple, but there is no simple method in Mathematica for these cases. I have been wondering why Mathematica doesn´t have a selection for this case like in the case of _Integer or sometimes ,Reals! I would like if the authors of Mathematica could introduce kind of Select [{ },_PositiveReals] option. Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

```
L = RandomSample[Join[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 1000], 
                      RandomComplex[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 1000]]];

Pick[L, Positive[L]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The question was to select positive real numbers, so it could be interpreted as

```
Select[list, Positive @ # && Head @ # === Real &]
```

> {11.2}

Answer (score 3):

```
Pick[#, HeavisideTheta@#, 1] &@{1, 11.2, -12, a, 0, 10 + I}
{*{1, 11.2}*}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 11.2, -12, a, 10 + I};
```

If we treat `1` as as a real number, we can use `PositiveReals` (new in V 12.0):

```
Select[list, # \[Element] PositiveReals &]
```

{1, 11.2}

This is in line with `RealValuedNumberQ` (new in V 13.3):

```
RealValuedNumberQ /@ {1, 11.2}
```

{True, True}

Recommended Reading:

[Real Numbers in the Wolfram Language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69525/real-numbers-in-the-wolfram-language)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 11.2, -12, a, 10 + I};
```

You can use `DeleteCases` as follows:

```
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; ! MatchQ[x, _?Positive]]

(*{1, 11.2}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[list, Positive], True]

(*{1, 11.2}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 11.2, -12, a, 10 + I, 0};
Pick[list, Sign@list, 1]
```

> {1, 11.2}