# For Loop to Sum numbers in a list

Tags: procedural-programming, homework

I'm asked to create a `For[]` loop that will sum positive numbers in a list. I am unsure of how to do this.

```
For[i = 0, i <= Length[List], i += 1, result += i];
```

`result`

This is what i have so far where List is the list of numbers and result is the summation of all the positive numbers. I am aware this is not right though.

Comment: Just to get it out of the way: see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609). Apart from class exercises, you shouldn't need to use `For[]`.

Comment: do you have example of such a list that you want to sum?

Comment: List={3, -5, 2, -12, -4, -1, -8, 10}

Comment: Better use `Total@*Ramp`... It is vectorized and thus much more efficient thatn top-level loops.

Comment: I do know it is not practical and I do appreciate the replies it just has to be a `For[]` Loop

Comment: A variation of @Henrik's proposal is `list.Unitize[Ramp[list]]`.

Comment: and so `list.UnitStep@list`

Answer (score 5):

```
bill = {3, -5, 2, -12, -4, -1, -8, 10};
Total[Select[bill, # > 0 &]]
```

An even shorter way, from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149565/selecting-positive-real-numbers-from-a-list), is

```
Total[Select[bill, Positive]]
```

The answer is 15. I believe that covers the OP's request, but it might be something more complicated. On documentation,

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html

Answer (score 4):

> List={3, -5, 2, -12, -4, -1, -8, 10}

There are many ways to do this in Mathematica, without using `For`.

One way could be to first filter out the positive numbers, then call `Total`

```
list = {3, -5, 2, -12, -4, -1, -8, 10};
positiveNumbersOnly = Cases[list, x_ /; Positive[x] -> x]

(*{3, 2, 10}*)

Total[positiveNumbersOnly]

(* 15*)
```

You can combine the above into one call

```
 Total@Cases[list, x_ /; Positive[x] -> x]
```

I am sure one can come up with 10 other ways to do this if needed.

For example

```
 Total[If[# > 0, #, 0] & /@ list]
 (* 15 *)
```

Another is

```
 Total[Clip[list, {0, Infinity}]]
 (* 15 *)
```

Comment: If using `Cases[]`, you could just do `Cases[list, x_?Positive]`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just for fun.

```
{3, -5, 2, -12, -4, -1, -8, 10} //. {b_, c_, a___} :> {Ramp[b] + Ramp[c], a}//First
```