# Selecting real pairs in a data set

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose we have a list of data, say,

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}}
```

I want to select a subset which includes only real pairs:

```
{{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
```

If I use `Re[data],`it also gives `{2, 1},`which I don' t want it. Is there any way to select those pairs 
for which both members are pure real?
  I need a program which works for long lists. In fact, I need a long list of data for `ListDensityPlot.` If any complex number is left, I won't be able to plot.

Comment: `dataReal = DeleteCases[data, _?(! FreeQ[#, Complex] &)]`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `FreeQ` and `Complex`, which will search each element of the list

`Select[data, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]`

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
> ```

Comment: In operator form: `data // Select[FreeQ[Complex]]`

Comment: Given {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}, the result is correct, however I doubt "Non-Complex Number" is equivalent to "Real Number". It's not actually.

Comment: @UnchartedWorks It is appropriate for the example input.  Even `Element` fails in some cases as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18673/121) and linked in jjc385's answer.  I love your concise code however (and I'm a little annoyed with myself I missed the opportunity to post that) and I just voted for your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I made an assumption too, I assumed     Element works, thanks for pointing it out that     Element is not what I thought.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a fast version:

```
Cases[data, {_Real | _Integer, _Real | _Integer}]
```

> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}

**Benchmark**

Using Mr.Wizard's benchmarking code:

```
big = Join[RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {5000, 2}], 
    RandomComplex[{-2 - I, 5 + 3 I}, {3000, 2}]] // RandomSample;

(*jjc385*) Select[big, And @@ Internal`RealValuedNumberQ /@ # &] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(*Mr.Wizard*) getReal = Pick[#, Unitize[Abs@Im@#.{1, 1}], 0] &;
    getReal[big] // Length // RepeatedTiming

(*UnchartedWorks*) (big // Select[# ∈ Reals &]) // Length // RepeatedTiming

(*KraZug*) Select[big, FreeQ[#, Complex] &] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.016, 5000}
>
> {0.0085, 5000}
>
> {0.0084, 5000}
>
> {0.0076, 5000}

This method is about 7 times faster:

```
Cases[big, {_Real | _Integer, _Real | _Integer}] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00109, 5000}

**Update: benchmarks of updated method of Mr. Wizard**

For pure numerical `data` (which can be converted to `PackedArray`), Mr. Wizard's method is twice faster than mine:

```
(*Mr.Wizard*)
Developer`ToPackedArray[getReal[Developer`ToPackedArray[big, Complex]], Real] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00055, 5000}

For `data` which are already in complex PackedArray form, Mr. Wizard's results are 5 times faster:

```
(*Mr.Wizard*)
big2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[big, Complex];
Developer`ToPackedArray[getReal[big2], Real] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00021, 5000}

**Conclusion**

Which filtering method is the fastest depends on the contents of your `data`.

If there are symbols (e.g. `Missing`) inside your `data`, then my solution is faster.

If `data` consists only from numbers (as in your example), it is faster to convert it to the PackedArray form and use Mr.Wizards solution.

Comment: Nice improvement. (+1)  Would you kindly time the additional code in my answer in version 11?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for an interesting update. The timings in version 11 are very close to what you got in v10. Your `PackedArray` solution is about 2 to 5 times faster then my pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty:

```
Select[data, And @@ Internal`RealValuedNumberQ /@ # &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
> ```

or, similarly but without a pure function:

```
Select[data, Apply[And] @* Map[Internal`RealValuedNumberQ] ]
```

---

I was somewhat surprised to find Mathematica is lacking a function `RealQ` to test whether a number is real.  [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/how-to-check-if-an-expression-is-a-real-valued-number) asked about this very thing, and I refer you to its answers, which explain how to implement such a function `realQ` on your own.  One example is

```
ClearAll[realQ]

realQ[x_List] := And @@ realQ /@ x
realQ[x_] := Internal`RealValuedNumberQ[x]
```

Then you can simplify the task at hand to

```
Select[data, realQ]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
> ```

Notice that this was much simpler from the `realQ[x_List]:= ...` definition, which says `realQ` acting on a list is only true if all of the elements of the list are real.

Answer (score 4):

Not nearly as clean as KraZug's method but a bit faster, if it matters

```
getReal = Pick[#, Unitize[Abs@Im@#.{1, 1}], 0] &;

getReal[data]
```

> ```
> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
> ```

Timings:

```
big = Join[RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {5000, 2}], 
    RandomComplex[{-2 - I, 5 + 3 I}, {3000, 2}]] // RandomSample;

Select[big, And @@ Internal`RealValuedNumberQ /@ # &] // Length // RepeatedTiming
Select[big, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]                      // Length // RepeatedTiming
getReal[big]                                          // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.017, 5000}
>
> {0.0097, 5000}
>
> {0.0072, 5000}
> ```

---

### Packed arrays

I chose `Pick` because it is fast on packed arrays, forgetting that the format I chose for `big` would not be packed.  This makes my method significantly less competitive as seen in Shadowray's answer.  However there *is* a case where it is much faster, even if that case now seems a little contrived.  If we force packing of `big` as Complex data `getReal` demonstrates the performance I was aiming for.  This can be followed by conversion to packed Real to clear out the `0. I` terms.  On the question example that looks like this:

```
Developer`ToPackedArray[data, Complex];
getReal[%]
Developer`ToPackedArray[%, Real]
```

> ```
> {{1. + 0. I, 3. + 0. I}, {-5. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I}, {3. + 0. I, 6. + 0. I}}
>
> {{1., 3.}, {-5., 0}, {3., 6.}}
> ```

If the ultimate target of this filtering is `ListDensityPlot` this format will be fine.

I cannot *directly* compare the performance of `getReal` on this packed Complex to other methods such as `Select[FreeQ[Complex]]` and `Cases[data, {_Real | _Integer, _Real | _Integer}]` as these *won't work* on the packed data.  I shall therefore compare their performance on unpacked `big` to `getReal` on the packed form I'll name `big2`.

```
big2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[big, Complex];

Select[big, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]                  // Length // RepeatedTiming
Cases[big, {_Real | _Integer, _Real | _Integer}]  // Length // RepeatedTiming
Developer`ToPackedArray[getReal[big2], Real]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0162, 5000}
>
> {0.01, 5000}
>
> {0.00114, 5000}
>
> {0.00019, 5000}
> ```

This doesn't include the initial conversion to packed Complex, which itself takes:

```
Developer`ToPackedArray[big, Complex]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00029, Null}
> ```

So *with* that overhead my code is 114 / (19 + 29) ~= 2.3 times faster than Shadowray's next-fastest code, and without that overhead it is almost four times faster.

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}};
data // Select[# ∈ Reals &]
```

Out:

> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}

If you use `FreeQ[#,Complex]&`, I don't think it's correct. I think the method with the fewest assumptions should be selected.
For instance.

In:

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}, {x, y}}
data // Select[# ∈ Reals &]
Select[data, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]
```

Out:

> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}
>
> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {x, y}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}};
Cases[data, {(_Integer|_Real)..}]
(* {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}, {Pi, E}};
```

Since `V 13.3` we have `RealValuedNumberQ` and `RealValuedNumericQ` :

```
Cases[data, {__?RealValuedNumberQ}]
```

{{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}}

```
Cases[data, {__?RealValuedNumericQ}]
```

{{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {Pi, E}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {2 - I, 1}, {I, -I}, {π, E}}; (* Thanks to  \@eldo *)
```

**Using `AllTrue`:**

```
Select[AllTrue[Head@# =!= Complex &]][data]
```

**Using `Except`:**

```
Cases[data, {Except[_Complex] ..}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 3}, {-5, 0}, {3, 6}, {π, E}}