# Why no RationalQ or RealQ?

Tags: expression-test, data-types, head

Interesting pattern came up as I go through the homework replies of my students. Why is there no `RationalQ` or `RealQ`? We have `Rational` and `Real` as type restrictors / heads in pattern matching, like `_Rational` or `_Real`. Why no Qs for them?

Comment: It's a good question, really, since we do have `IntegerQ`. If you need something like that, you can always use a curried form like `RationalQ = MatchQ[_Rational]`.

Comment: No good answer to this one ... but people regularly make the mistake of assuming that `IntegerQ` tests if an expression is mathematically an integer (what it does is that it checks if the datatype is `Integer`)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Good idea, but I can "break" it: `RationalQ[(1 - Sqrt[2]) (1 + Sqrt[2])]`. ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: How does that break it? I wouldn't expect a function like `RationalQ` to perform algebraic simplifications: it should just check the data type. If you want to simplify, you should use `Simplify`. Mathematica already has enough annoying simplification behaviours that are difficult to stop.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Good point. Even `IntegerQ` cannot simplify that.

Comment: For the math (not datatype), one would use `Element[x, Rationals]` instead. That will often not evaluate, but it is `Simplify`able.  It doesn't check datatype. It's checks whether the value is rational.

Comment: If there were a `RationalQ`, I'd expect `RationalQ[2]` to be `False` because the datatype of `2` is `Integer`, not `Rational`. That has nothing to do with `2` being a rational number.

Comment: Related question on [RealQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18647/58370)

Comment: `_Rational` is not sufficient as `Rational[x,y]` with (`x`,`y` symbols) is not an atomic `Rational`. There should be a `RationalQ`.

Answer (score 23):

There is a `RealQ`, see

```
Developer`RealQ
```

Also relevant:

```
Developer`MachineRealQ
```

The difference between the two:

```
Developer`RealQ[1.`20]
Developer`MachineRealQ[1.`20]
```

> True
>
> False

So, `` Developer`RealQ `` is a test for arbitrary precision numbers, while `` Developer`MachineRealQ `` checks whether its input is a double precision number.

Notice that both return

```
Developer`RealQ[1]
Developer`MachineRealQ[1]
```

> False
>
> False

Compare this to

```
IntegerQ[10^100000]
Developer`MachineIntegerQ[10^100000]
```

> True
>
> False

As Szabolcs and Sjoerd pointed out, these tests are for data types and not tests in mathematical sense. For example, we also have the following:

```
IntegerQ[(1 - Sqrt[2]) (1 + Sqrt[2])]
IntegerQ[Simplify[(1 - Sqrt[2]) (1 + Sqrt[2])]]
```

> False
>
> True

A somewhat more mathematical test seems to be `` Assumptions`ARealQ ``:

```
Assumptions`ARealQ[(1 - Sqrt[2]) (1 + Sqrt[2])]
```

> True

But as it is undocumented, I really don't know what does it do.

And on top of that, we have `` Assumptions`ARationalQ ``, quite a mysterious beast:

```
Assumptions`ARationalQ[(1 - Sqrt[2]) (1 + Sqrt[2])]
Assumptions`ARationalQ[1/2]
Assumptions`ARationalQ[1]
Assumptions`ARationalQ[I]
Assumptions`ARationalQ[1.]
```

> False
>
> True
>
> True
>
> False
>
> False

Not to mention `` Reduce`RationalNumberQ `` which behaves similarly erratic.

Comment: `(1 - 3 I) + (I ArcSinh[7])/ArcSinh[1]` is a real number, but Developer`RealQ and MachineRealQ  returns False.

Comment: Of course it is not a machine real, because it is an exact number. Only `Re[N[(1 - 3 I) + (I ArcSinh[7])/ArcSinh[1]]]` would turn it into a machine real. E.g., also ``Developer`MachineRealQ[1]`` would return `False`. I think that `` Developer`MachineRealQ`` works as it should. I don't now however, why ``Developer`RealQ`` does not classify it as a real number. Both functions are undocument and thus so not meant for the public. We just cannot tell what the designers intendended and whether they work correctly in that regard.

Answer (score 17):

> Why no RationalQ or RealQ?

Probably because it isn't unambiguous what such a function should do.  [From the comments above:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/why-no-rationalq-or-realq#comment474635_181761)

> If there were a `RationalQ`, I'd expect `RationalQ[2]` to be `False`

But many other users would expect something like this:

[image]

For `IntegerQ` there aren't such conflicting expectations.