# How do I check if this expression is real?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I check if the result of:

```
Integrate[Cos[Sqrt[GM/r^3]], r]
```

is real for real `GM` and `r`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why no RationalQ or RealQ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/why-no-rationalq-or-realq)

Comment: Well, it is straight-foward to disprove it: `bla = Integrate[Cos[Sqrt[GM/r^3]], r];
Table[Im[bla], {GM, -1, 1, .1}, {r, -1, 1, 0.1}]`